# wkhtmltopdf - dynamically change page margins without overwritting content

Tags: javascript, php, html, symfony, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtml with symfony2 via an external command to generate pdf reports from twig files.
I'm encountering an issue while trying to increase the page top margin starting from the second page with javascript; the content on the second page is overwritten.
Is that even possible to achieve that?
Is there a better alternative than wkhtml?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the bundle knp-snappy-bundle for doing your PDF.
He work with wkhtmltopdf.

https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle

Comment: KnpSnappyBundle is just a wrapper for wkhtml. My question is if it is possible or not to change the top margin starting from the second page with wkhtml(or KnpSnappyBundle) without overwriting the content..

Comment: test by adding a CSS property (or ressource) in PDF mode.

Comment: that's what I did via javascript but it overrides the content

Comment: i have made somthing as you describ with a template inheritance